# Using Google Earth Engine node_module in Laravel application

Tags: laravel, api, google-earth-engine

I working on web application with Laravel framework and I need to use Google Earth Engine Javascript API in my application and I have installed with `npm install --save @google/earthengine` and it has been installed without any issue, located in my project `node_modules/@google/earthengine` but I don't know how to  use it in my application I have tried with [NPM Installation Google Earth Engine API](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/npm_install) but there is no in details instruction in this regard.

Comment: Once installed you can consume the library: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/npm_install#setting-up-authentication-credentials

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier I did that I have created Client_id and privateKay but I don't know where should I load that module and how.

Comment: usually javascript goes in `resources/js/...` and it is then transpiled using [laravel-mix](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix)